# Create a "nice" form programmatically

Tags: javascript, dojo

For my dialog

```
var dia = new Dialog({
    content: form,
    title: 'Create a new test',
    style: "width: 300px; height: 165px;"
});
```

I want to create a "nice" formated form.

At the moment I do something like this:

```
var form = new Form();

form.domNode.appendChild(dojo.doc.createTextNode("Name:"));

new TextBox({
    placeHolder: "Name"
}).placeAt(form.containerNode);

form.domNode.appendChild(dojo.doc.createTextNode("Upload File:"));

new Uploader({ name: "File",
    label: "Select file",
    id: "addDia",
    multiple: false,
    uploadOnSelect: false,
    url: "to/the/ethreal"
}).placeAt(form.containerNode);

new FileList({
   uploader: up
}).placeAt(form.containerNode);
```

Problem: The form arranges the elemts arbitrary. How to achieve something like this:

```
"Label text:" TextBox
"Label text:" Uploader
FileList
```

Or a vertical arrangement:

```
"Label text:"
TextBox
"Label text:" 
Uploader
FileList
```

Comment: Cascading Style Sheets?

Comment: I dont want to overwrite the dojo internal css.

Comment: Then you will have to live with how it is currently styled. And why do you care about "internal" - css is *cascading*?

Comment: Yeah you are right. But I would prefer it to create at first somehow own <div> elements in that form as wrapper and THEN to style the <div> elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without CSS something like this:

```
var form = new Form();

var p = dojo.create("div", {}, form.domNode); 
p.appendChild(dojo.doc.createTextNode("Name:"));
new TextBox({
  placeHolder: "Name"
}).placeAt(p);

p = dojo.create("p", {}, form.domNode);
p.appendChild(dojo.doc.createTextNode("Upload file:"));
var up = new Uploader({ name: "File",
    label: "Select file",
    id: "addDia",
    multiple: false,
    uploadOnSelect: false,
    url: "to/the/ethreal"
}).placeAt(p);
```

for

```
"Label text:" TextBox
"Label text:" Uploader
```